# Nested Constraint Layout not showing if using Match_Constraints

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a nested ConstraintLayout in Android.

The objective is to have an Image to the left, and another constraint layout to the right, inside a constraint layout, as the following image:

[image]

It correctly shows on the preview, but inside the application, it bugs and doesn't show at all
[image]

Layout File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/box_npcs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/npcImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutInformation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layoutInformation"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorBlueishGreen" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutInformation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.021"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/npcImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top_priority"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:text="DummyTextIsDummy"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_default"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout is being added to another ConstraintLayout using the code

```
parent.addChild(inflater.inflate(R.layout.box_npc);
```

How should I fix this? And even, what is the issue?

Comment: Works fine on my emulator and looks like the design view. Make sure that you have the latest library for `ConstraintLayout` - `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2`.

Comment: I'm using the latest library, unsure now what I can do to fix it...

Comment: Does it work exactly as I'm showing?

Comment: Yes. I did change the image and text color since I don't have those available.

Comment: I'm testing on a Galaxy Samsumg s5 (physical). Maybe that's an issue?

Comment: Maybe. Clean the project and try a different device/emulator.

Comment: I don't have the availability to test with a different device nor an emulator (non-intel cpu). Can you check with a Samsumg and see if that's it?

Comment: Not near a computer. Will try tomorrow if you're still having a problem.

Comment: One thought make sure your text is not the same color as your background

Comment: Text isn't the same color as background. I can't spot the issue

Comment: Tried the code on a Samsung S7 and everything works A-OK. Here is the [project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/MyApplication2) I used on GitHub. Maybe it can help you figure out what is going on with your project. As I said before, I just changed the image and the text color.

Comment: I'll try to debug it using your git project. Still don't know the bug, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation faced was that OP was trying to add the created ConstraintLayout to another ConstraintLayout programatically. That was being made using

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.box, null)
```

It was an incorrect approach, as this ignores the layout parameters from the box. What was made to fix it was

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.box, PARENT_LAYOUT/* One that box was being added to*/)
```

This fixes some issues due to the fact that the layout parameters were now being respected by the parent layout.

More information: [Understaing Android's Layout Inflater.inflate()](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)

Comment: I am not inflating it from the code, still facing the same issue. Can you help, please?

Answer (score 2):

For child views of each inner ConstraintLayout, use the id of parent layout instead of "parent". 
For example instead of:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Use

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/parent_id"
```

Comment: For Googlers of the future: if you are getting `error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toTopof not found` or similar, it may because you have made the mistake this answer corrects.