# ConstraintLayout set width to full width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have main constraint layout, and also additional layout footer where i inflate it and add it to my main constraint. The problem is even though i set constraint to set the width to full (match_parent) its not working it center the view but it wrap content its not extended through all screen. Here is my code:

Footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The main layout is basically empty constraint layout, and than in code i set following:

```
View footerRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
footerRow.setId(R.id.constraint_footer);
mainView.addView(footerRow);

ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(mainView);
set.connect(footerRow.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
set.connect(footerRow.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
set.connect(footerRow.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
set.applyTo(mainView);
```

Comment: Try to set width of your imageview to `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: `match_parent`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `match_constraint` or `0dp`

> Widgets dimension constraints
>   The dimension of the widgets can be specified by setting the android:layout_width and android:layout_height attributes in 3 different ways:
>
> - Using a specific dimension (either a literal value such as 123dp or a
>     Dimension reference)
> - Using WRAP_CONTENT, which will ask the widget to compute its own size
> - Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Comment: But how do you actually do that programmatically? That's what the question is asking

Answer (score 0):

Basically this question solved my problem: [Nested Constraint Layout not showing if using Match_Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021472/nested-constraint-layout-not-showing-if-using-match-constraints)

i was not attaching it to parent layout.

Comment: Mark this question as answered or remove it completely.